# Select some values in a SQL query while ignoring the Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

First of all I have this SQL query:

```
DECLARE @list TABLE 
(
    [DocID] int,
    [OrderQuantity] decimal(18,3)
)

INSERT INTO @list (DocID, OrderQuantity)
    (SELECT 
         tblCusDocsPos.DocID, tblCusDocsPos.OrderQuantity, 
     FROM 
         tblCusDocsPos
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         tblCusDocsPos ON tblCusDocsPos.DocID = tblCusDocsPos.DocID 
     WHERE 
         (tblCusDocs.ActualAB = 0)
     GROUP BY 
         tblCusDocsPos.DocID , tblCusDocsPos.OrderQuantity)

SELECT 
    [tblCusDocs].[DocID], [tblCusDocs].[DocTypeID],
    [tblCusDocs].[ContractNum],
    [tblCusDocs].[OrderQuantity], list.OrderQuantity
FROM 
    tblCusDocs
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [tblCusDocsPos] ON [tblCusDocsPos].DocID = [tblCusDocs].DocID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    @list ON list.DocID = [tblCusDocs].DocID
WHERE 
    [tblCusDocs].ActualAB = 1
```

The problem here is the following: I'm inserting values into my table called `list` with the condition `ActualAB = 0`. Now the table is getting filled but in the main `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT` statement. These values are getting thrown out because of the condition `ActualAB = 1`.

Is it possible to ignore the main where clause for the items in my list table and return all values from there? Can this be done in one query?

Thanks very much.

EDIT:

this is getting bound to a grid over properties at the end. So we are using a kind of loader which evaluates the `SELECT` statement and receives all data but because of the `WHERE` clause at the end the values from the list table are getting filtered a second time.
So the Output should be one table with values. Three columns that are filtered by the main `WHERE` clause and one (list.OrderQuantity) which is filtered by the `WHERE` clause above.

EDIT2:

Ok I'm trying to explain it more clearly with Kind of sample table with data.

I'm filtering from a table with such content:

`DocID | AB | OrderQuantity | ContractNum`

`1        1         2            111`

`2        0         5            111`

`3        1         0            222`

`4        1         10           333`

`5        1         3            444`

In this case I would get all values with AB=1 because of the main `WHERE` clause.
Let's say I'm filtering over the ContractNum. In my case I would like to have also four results but when I have the same ContractNums, i would rather choose the OrderQuantity value where AB=1.

Comment: just remove the where clause if you don't want it??

Comment: No the WHERE clause has to be there because of the other values which are in my tblCusDocs table. So I need to filter the values from one table with AB=0 and from the other with AB=1 in one such statement.

Comment: maybe if you give us some sample data and expected outcome to make clear what you want

Comment: Ok I edited. Hope this is clearer now.

Comment: Are you looking for a CTE?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I think no. Because the CTE described has a table with values and filters again values from this table, right? I would need to select all values which are filtered separately, not depending on each other.

Comment: Sounds like you need 2 data sets combined into one. Try a `UNION` of your statements.

Comment: Doesn't a `Union` gives me all results of the first and of the second table?

Comment: I think you don't need a @list table, calculate counts using `APPLY`. You can calculate row priority with `ROW_NUMBER` and select first row only

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark guess that you want results where the ActualAB = 1 OR the result is in the list table.

```
DECLARE @list TABLE 
(
    [DocID] int,
    [OrderQuantity] decimal(18,3)
)

INSERT INTO @list (DocID, OrderQuantity)
    (SELECT 
         tblCusDocsPos.DocID, tblCusDocsPos.OrderQuantity, 
     FROM 
         tblCusDocsPos
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         tblCusDocsPos ON tblCusDocsPos.DocID = tblCusDocsPos.DocID 
     WHERE 
         (tblCusDocs.ActualAB = 0)
     GROUP BY 
         tblCusDocsPos.DocID , tblCusDocsPos.OrderQuantity)

SELECT 
    [tblCusDocs].[DocID], [tblCusDocs].[DocTypeID],
    [tblCusDocs].[ContractNum],
    [tblCusDocs].[OrderQuantity], list.OrderQuantity
FROM 
    tblCusDocs
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [tblCusDocsPos] ON [tblCusDocsPos].DocID = [tblCusDocs].DocID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    @list ON list.DocID = [tblCusDocs].DocID
WHERE 
    [tblCusDocs].ActualAB = 1 OR list.DocID IS NOT NULL
```